# Database Password Decryption in UWP

Tags: c#, laravel, uwp, bcrypt

I'm a beginner at Universal Windows Platform. I am using Php My admin for my database using web services. Now I'm struck at login. In database, The password is in Bcrypted or Hashed. I don't know how to decrypt it in C# or UWP.

Comment: It's likely to be hashed. There is no way to "unhash" it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't **decrypt** it at all (or "dehash" - which isn't really possible, kind of the whole point of it). Instead **encrypt** the user input too and check if the hashes match.

C# comes with a wide range of hashing algorithms (can be found in the `Windows.Security.Cryptography` or `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace) that you can use to hash the user input.

If the algorithm that you need isn't available there, you could try [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't programatically decrypt a hashed password, you need to encrypt the password that the user put into the login form using the same method and then check if the 2 hash results match up

I would suggest that you do a lot of additional reading on the subject of user management, and pick an existing framework to handle this for you

Some more information about your project would probably help people to suggest the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

```
private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```